# Django 1.9 app name not defined

Tags: django, django-urls

I've read quite a few solutions to similar answers. Most being an import is missing or quote marks. I can't seem to spot my mistake. Please advise. 
I get an error on my_app(exams).urls that exams is not defined. 'etaExams' is my main project and the app name is 'exams'.

etaExams.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^exams/', include('exams.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

exams.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', exams.views.home, name='home'),
]
```

exams.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def home(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My settings file has 'exams' under installed apps. 
The above code runs if I remove 'exams' in both urls.py files 
     `url(r'', include('exams.urls')),`
and

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

In this case the local time displays here `http://localhost:56669/` instead of `http://localhost:56669/exams`

Last things that's strange is in my admin site the section for "Sites" is missing.

I'm adding my file layout from VisualStudio. I deleted the project/*init*.py file according to [this](https://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions/543107) post. It makes no difference at all.
[File listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNXts.png)

Comment: In Django 1.9, `django.contrib.sites` is not included in `INSTALLED_APPS` by default when you start a new project. If you need it, you'll have to [enable it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework).

Comment: Your question might be clearer if you show the layout of your project files. Are you getting errors when you run the server, or are they just errors in Intelligence.

Comment: Added my file list from VS solution tree in my question above. Thanks for your effort. The server doesn't run, it stops saying that exams are not defined. The only way I get it to work at the moment is to use relative import with `url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),` but there must be a way to add exams to the url.
Also, my import for views (exams and the relative option) both gives the IntelliSense warning.

Comment: If the relative import is working, can't you use `url(r'^exams/', include('exams.urls'))` in `etaExams/urls.py`, then use the relative import and `url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')` in `exams/urls.py`. Doesn't that give you what you want?

Comment: Your `etaExams/etaExams` folder (the one that contains `settings.py` **should** contain an `__init__.py`. The `etaExams` folder (the one that contains `manage.py` should not).

Comment: Fixed that now (updated attachment in main question). Still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `exams/urls.py`, You have imported `exams.views` as `views` with a relative import:

```
from . import views
```

So you should use `views`, not `exams.views` in your URL patterns.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

If you then include your exam urls with the following include in `etaExams.urls.py`, then you should get the URL layout you want.

```
url(r'^exams/', include('exams.urls')),
```

You should be able to do `import exams.views` in `exams/urls.py`, then use `exams.views.home` in your URL pattern. You say this isn't working in the comments, but I don't understand why it wouldn't work. I prefer the relative import to `import exams.views` anyway.

Comment: `import exams.views`
    `urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', exams.views.home, name='home'),
    ]`
This still says exams not defined. Also tried changing it to 'from exams import views'

Comment: I'm not sure why that's not working for you, but I recommend that you use `from . import views` and `url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),` anyway.

Comment: I now have `url(r'^exams/', include('exams.urls')),` in `etaExams/urls.py` and I have `from . import views` in `exams/urls.py` along with `url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),` 
This runs the server with a 404 error. This also includes the `_init_.py` fix you mentioned above.


If I change `etaExams/urls.py` to `url(r'', include('exams.urls')),` it works, but that's not the structure I want. I want it to display in `localhost.../exams`

Comment: If you have `url(r'^exams/', include('exams.urls')),`, then I **would** expect `http://localhost:56669/` to give a 404 error, because you haven't defined any url patterns for `^$` in `etaExams/urls.py`. If you then go to `http://localhost:56669/exams/`, your `home` view should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```